# Solving Vieta's jumping problem (1988 IMO problem 6) with a cubic polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, induction, contest-math, cubics

I have recently watched this [Numberphile video](https://youtu.be/NcaYEaVTA4g) explaining how Zvezdelina Stankova solved the notorious 1988 IMO problem 6 as a student.

(Most of you will know this problem)

> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers, if $k$ is an integer, prove that
> $k$ is a perfect square.
>
> $$ \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy+1} = k $$

In this video, she says that her solution included a "**cubic polynomial**" and "induction", but she can't remember her solution.

She added, "I remember my teammate solved this problem with quadratic polynomial and induction, and I remember his solution to this day."

His solution, obviously, is the well-known [Vieta's jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Standard_Vieta_jumping) method, and it doesn't involve cubic polynomials.

How can this problem involve **cubic polynomial** while solving?

Questions on this problem are maybe outdated, but I still want to find answers or some hints.

Comment: You'd be more likely to get answers to this question if you stated the problem in full. No need to require people to click on a video, which might not even have a timestamp showing where the problem is stated in it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have thought that this problem is quite popular, so I didn't mention it on this post. But as you suggested I have added details to this post. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly she did something like $x^2+y^2=xyk +k$, which is technically cubic in three variables? Sadly she doesn't remember and, apparently, neither does anyone else. ------ I would say that the video isn't standard Vieta jumping, though. She never used a contradiction, she uses induction--but frankly, I've watched that video twice and still don't understand how what Dr Stankova provides is actually a proof, while your link to Vieta jumping on WP makes more sense than the video!

Comment: @EricSnyder I have thought the same way. I can't actually understand the video.
I think other students who solved this problem possibly used similar contradiction techniques. But the solution using **cubic** is still a mystery

Comment: @EricSnyder I think I have found some clue (https://www.emis.de/journals/BAMV/conten/vol18/BAMV_XVIII-2_p143-152.pdf). On page 145, 8. mentions a cubic polynomial. Do you think this is relevant?